# Buy a genuine arduino board or a sainsmart board?

Tags: arduino-uno

Arduino Day is so popular! Many boards are cheap during arduino day. So should I buy a [genuine arduino board](https://day.arduino.cc/#/) or [a sainsmart board?](http://eepurl.com/biaWzT)

Comment: You should get the one that satisfies your requirements.

Comment: You should clarify your question and tell what you intend to do with it, so that we get a chance to give you hints on selection...

Comment: It looks like they are pretty much identical. So it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 3):

Buying an official board can be a good choice for a couple of main reasons. First of all, you're guaranteed a good quality board which conforms to the official schematic, and is definitely compatible with any relevant official software and hardware. If the board turns out to be faulty when you get it, you'll be able to get it replaced. Additionally, buying official boards means some of the money you spend goes towards funding future Arduino projects.

As you've no doubt seen, cloned (i.e. unofficial) boards based on Arduino are often much cheaper. Nonetheless, many of the boards are very good. Functionally, you might not see any difference whatsoever from the official/genuine boards. Some of them actually have some additional features which you might find useful depending on your project, such as switching the IO pins between 3.3v and 5v.

However, not all cloned boards are worth using. Some of them may have lower quality components. It's even possible that they weren't designed/constructed correctly in the first place. This could lead to a range of problems, from incompatibilities through to outright failure of the hardware. Given the geographic location of some of the manufacturers/sellers, you may not have any way to get a refund if something goes wrong.

If you choose to use a clone, look for a brand which other people have had success with. Also do your best to ensure the board uses the correct microcontroller (e.g. the Atmega328 for boards based on the Uno).

Ultimately, the decision is up to you. There's no 'right' answer necessarily.

Comment: With the current Arduino board, you might be supporting the wrong side, when buying an official board.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the number of complaints seen about Sainsmart assemblies in the Arduino forum, I would suggest original.

You're also less likely to get a "go ask in the Sainsmart forum" reply when you ask for help in the Arduino forum.